# Visually permute rows of a matrix via mouse dragging

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, eventhandler

I'm looking for a way to permute the rows of a matrix visually via mouse dragging, for example by clicking and dragging on a row in the MatrixPlot corresponding to the matrix.

What would be the best way to achieve something like this?
By best I here mean in terms of efficiency and readability/scalability of implementation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

EDIT: converted the use of explicit `Hold` wrappers to appropriate `HoldAll` and `HoldFirst` attributes of helper functions.
Also added possibility to change columns together with rows, and added highlighting of rows/columns that are being moved.

The following is a possible implementation, allowing to visually switch neighbouring rows and columns via mouse dragging the corresponding MatrixPlot of the matrix.

If a symbol containing a matrix is passed to the function, the value of the matrix is changed in-place, so that this can be thought of as a way to visually change a matrix.

To start, I defined an helper function `MP`, which is nothing but a `MatrixPlot` with some commonly used options:

```
(* MP is just a shorthand for MatrixPlot, with some predefined commonly used
   options *)
Options @ MP = Options @ MatrixPlot;
MP[expr_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := MatrixPlot[
  expr,
  Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Options @ MatrixPlot],
  PlotRangePadding -> None,
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Gray
];
```

The code implementing the functionality is then the following:

```
rowNumber[matrix_] := If[# === None, #,
  If[
    MatchQ[#, _Integer ? (1 <= # <= Length @ matrix &)],
    #, None
  ] & [
    1 + Length @ matrix - Last @ Floor[# + 1]
  ]
] & @ MousePosition["Graphics"];


colNumber[matrix_] := If[# === None, #,
  If[
    MatchQ[#, _Integer ? (1 <= # <= Last @ Dimensions @ matrix &)],
    #, None
  ] & [
    First @ Floor[# + 1]
  ]
] & @ MousePosition["Graphics"];


mouseOnGraphics[] := MousePosition["Graphics"] =!= None;


switchRows[matrix_, row1_, row2_] := ReplacePart[matrix,
  {row1 -> matrix[[row2]],
   row2 -> matrix[[row1]]}
];


switchCols[matrix_, col1_, col2_] := ReplacePart[matrix,
  {
    {row_, col1} :> matrix[[row, col2]],
    {row_, col2} :> matrix[[row, col1]]
  }
];


(* Replace neighboring rows or columns, conditionally to the value of `which`.
   The change is done in-place, that is, the value of `matrixVar` is changed
   directly. *)
Attributes @ switchNeighborsInPlace = HoldFirst;
switchNeighborsInPlace[
  matrixVar_, idx1_, idx2_, which : ("Rows" | "Cols")
] := Set[matrixVar,
  Which[
    which == "Cols",
    switchCols[matrixVar, idx1, idx2],
    which == "Rows",
    switchRows[matrixVar, idx1, idx2]
  ]
];


Attributes @ conditionallySwitchNeighbors = HoldAll;
conditionallySwitchNeighbors[
  matrix_, labelsList_, oldIdx_, newIdx_, which : ("Rows" | "Cols")
] := If[
  Abs[oldIdx - newIdx] == 1 // TrueQ,
  switchNeighborsInPlace[matrix, oldIdx, newIdx, which];
  labelsList[[{oldIdx, newIdx}]] = labelsList[[{newIdx, oldIdx}]];
  oldIdx = newIdx
];


drawHighlightingRectangles[len_, row_, col_] := {
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness @ 0.01}],
  If[NumericQ @ row,
    Rectangle[{0, len - row}, {len, len - row + 1}],
    Sequence[]
  ],
  FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Purple, Thickness @ 0.01}],
  If[NumericQ @ col,
    Rectangle[{col - 1, 0}, {col, len}],
    Sequence[]
  ]
};


makeFrameTicks[len_Integer, labels_List] := {
  {#, #}, {#, #}
} & @ Thread @ {Range @ len, labels};

makeFrameTicks[lenghts_List, labelsRows_List, labelsCols_List] := {
  {#1, #1}, {#2, #2}
} & [
  Thread @ {Range @ lenghts[[1]], labelsRows},
  Thread @ {Range @ lenghts[[2]], labelsCols}
];

makeFrameTicks[labels_List] := makeFrameTicks[Length @ labels, labels];
makeFrameTicks[labelsRows_List, labelsCols_List] := makeFrameTicks[
  Length /@ {labelsRows, labelsCols}, labelsRows, labelsCols
];


Attributes @ dynamicMatrixPlot = HoldFirst;

Options @ dynamicMatrixPlot = {"OverlayRectangles" -> False};

dynamicMatrixPlot[matrix_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := If[
  (* If the input is directly given as a matrix, we make local variable holding
     it and recall the function with that variable as argument *)
  ! MatchQ[Hold @ matrix, Hold @ _Symbol],
  Module[{mat = matrix}, dynamicMatrixPlot[mat, opts]],

  With[{overlayRectangles = TrueQ @ OptionValue @ "OverlayRectangles"},
  DynamicModule[{
      len = Length @ matrix,
      oldRow, oldCol,
      rowsOrder = Range @ Length @ matrix,
      colsOrder = Range @ Length @ matrix
    },
    EventHandler[
      Dynamic @ MP[matrix,
        (* Epilog is used to draw the rectangles highlighting the row/column
           that is being moved *)
        If[overlayRectangles,
          Epilog -> drawHighlightingRectangles[len, oldRow, oldCol],
          Unevaluated @ Sequence[]
        ],
        FrameTicks -> makeFrameTicks @@ {rowsOrder, colsOrder}
      ],
      {
        "MouseDown" :> (
          Set[oldRow, rowNumber @ matrix];
          Set[oldCol, colNumber @ matrix]
        ),
        "MouseDragged" :> (
          If[And[
              mouseOnGraphics[],
              rowNumber @ matrix =!= None,
              colNumber @ matrix =!= None
            ],
            (* conditionallySwitchNeighbors handles the switching of neighboring
               rows and columns. Note that it also changes in-place `oldRow`
               and `oldCol`. *)
            conditionallySwitchNeighbors[
              matrix, rowsOrder, oldRow, rowNumber @ matrix, "Rows"
            ];
            conditionallySwitchNeighbors[
              matrix, colsOrder, oldCol, colNumber @ matrix, "Cols"
            ]
          ];
        )
      }
    ]
  ]]
];
```

The main idea is pretty simple: `MP` (or, equivalently, `MatrixPlot`) is used to draw the matrix, and an `EventHandler` wraps the whole `MP` handling the `MouseDown` and `MouseDragged` events.

To use it just call `dynamicMatrixPlot` over the target matrix:

[image]

The function can also be used to modify a pre-existing matrix:

```
matrix = HamadardMatrix @ 4;
dynamicMatrixPlot @ matrix
```

will change `matrix` to be what is currently shown in the plot.

The implementation is surely not optimal.
In particular, when the kernel is quitted the plots disappear, basically because `MP` and the local variables created by `Module` are not defined anymore.
I'm not sure how to fix this though, suggestions are welcome!

Comment: If you place your local variables in `DynamicModule` they will be cached. Define initialization code in a `CompoundExpression` in the `Initialization` option to `DynamicModule`.